# Selecting words out of table which sound similar

Tags: t-sql, fuzzy-search

I read an interesting article about English and phonetics - and would like to see if my newfound knowledge can be applied in TSQL to generate a fuzzy result set. In one of my applications, there is a table containing words, which I extracted from a word list. It is literally a one-column table -

```
Word |
------
A
An
Apple
...
their
there
```

Is there an built-in function in SQL Server to Select a word which **Sounds** The same, even though it is spelled different? (The globalization settings are on `en-ZA` - as last time I checked)

```
SELECT Word FROM WordTable WHERE Word = <word that sounds similar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SoundEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx)

> SOUNDEX converts an alphanumeric string to a four-character code that is based on how the string sounds when spoken.

[Difference()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx)

> Returns an integer value that indicates the difference between the SOUNDEX values of two character expressions.

```
SELECT word
     , SoundEx(word) As word
     , SoundEx(word_that_sounds_similar) As word_that_sounds_similar
     , Difference(SoundEx(word), SoundEx(word_that_sounds_similar)) As how_similar
FROM   wordtable
WHERE  Difference(SoundEx(word), SoundEx(word_that_sounds_similar)) <= 1 /* quite close! */
```

The value returned by `Difference()` indicates how similar the two words are.

A value of **0** indicates a *strong match* and a value of **4** means slim-to-no match.

Comment: This is so badass. This code worked, and I gained +1 to my intellect stat :D. Thank you